# Understanding Boyer-Moore string search algorithm's "Good Suffix Shift"-Table

Tags: c, boyer-moore

Please help me to understand Boyer-Moore string search algorithm's ["Good Suffix Shift"-Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm#The_first_table).

What has happened when `i==3`?

There is no sub-string "_MAN" in the pattern. So the shift value should be 8 (as it was when `i==1`).

Why is it `6`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no sub-string "_MAN", but the string does start with "AN", so if you shift over by 6 you could get a pattern that matches as follows

```
_ M A N _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ A N P A N M A N
```

Comment: So the calculation becomes recursive isn't it? That is searching a substring within a substring.

Comment: This is what the preprocessing part of the algorithm does: because the string starts and ends with the same two letters, if you get a bad match then you can shift over by 6 characters and potentially have another match.